# Using primary key in ArcSDE Enterprise Geodatabase with MS SQL Server?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

Does setting a primary key constraint in a field obstruct the compression of a versioned geodatabase?

I read someone mentioning that the primary key in a versioned geo-database will cause problem while compressing the geo-database.

I have a cadastral database in ArcSDE 9.x (MS SQL Server 2008). I have a field **parcel id** which  is the primary key.

Comment: It's not the *compression* that's impacted, but editing itself (if the PK is applied to the adds table). Still, primary keys are not recommended, especially if you don't have a thorough understanding of the versioned editing model. Note that SQL Server 2008 hasn't been supported for much of this decade, and ArcGIS 9.x is so old it's a different product (there was a huge data model change at 10.0).